# DC motor speed control

Tags: microcontroller, motor, pwm, atmega, embedded

I am trying to control the speed of motor using ADC value received using ATMega16, the system works well with 12V. But when I go for 24V the motor runs continuously, even when ADC value is 0.

I have checked with oscilloscope, the PWM output suddenly goes HIGH and remains HIGH even when ADC input is 0.

[image]

I believe that the code is correct since the system works perfect in case of 12V.

```
#include<avr\io.h>
#include<avr\interrupt.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>

int del;
int x,x1,z,z1;
int rpm = 0;

int main (void)
{
    DDRA = 0X00;
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    DDRC = 0xFF;    
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    ADCSRA = 0x87;
    ADMUX = 0xC0;                   // Selecting ADC0

    while (1)
    {   


        ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
        while ((ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)) == 0);
        {
            x = ADCL;
            PORTD = x;
            x1 = ADCH;
            PORTC = x1;
            del = ADCL;
            del |= ADCH << 8;
            del = (del-512)/50;

            if (del > 0)
            {
            PORTB = 0x08;
            _delay_ms(del);
            PORTB = 0x00;
            _delay_ms(10-del);
            }

            else
            {
            PORTB = 0x00;
            }
        }
```

MOSFET Datasheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/205/ixys_98625-342386.pdf

[image]

[Link to setup](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YtB6BaMJDRqPOR902)

Comment: wrt edited question : something the motor is doing is interfering with the CPU (crashing it or latching it up). I see far too little decoupling on the PSU for a start, and no protection on PortB.3 against spikes fed back (e.g. via the Miller capacitance) through the MOSFET gate. Also, the MOSFET is big and slow; what is your PWM frequency?

Comment: PWM frequency: 1Khz.
The MOSFET is big because later this circuit will be used to run a 60V motor, with a heavy load. 

How do you suggest I proceed with the interference part ?

Comment: @KanishakKatahra Why haven't you added a series resistor to the MOSFET gate (limit oscillation and current limit) and a resistor from gate to ground (MOSFETs at low gate voltages look like constant-current sinks instead of switches that are OFF.)

Comment: What values should the resistors be ?
You are suggesting that the MOSFET be in OFF state unless a resistor from gate to ground is added ?

Comment: @KanishakKatahra Since MCUs often have about \$50-100\:\Omega\$ series impedance anyway, and your MOSFET gate is in the nF range, try \$220\:\Omega\$ for the series resistance. Also tie the gate down to ground with perhaps \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$? I don't know your switching requirements, but as far as guesses go those are as good as any. If that doesn't help, then it's a different problem or else you need an even more extreme driver change.

Comment: @KanishakKatahra Then the \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ to ground may be okay. The RC constant is better than \$\tau=100\:\mu\text{s}\$. (It takes a few \$\tau\$ to get where you want to go.) You could decrease the pull-down further. But then your divider voltage will be a little lower and the ON resistance may go up a little in reply. It's up to you. I can't really do a design for you here.

Comment: 'Ground loop' is another possibility. Can you post a photo of your setup, with battery/motor/MCU power wiring shown?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The link of the setup and an image of the PCB has been added.

Comment: Unfortunately your photos are not clear enough to trace all the wiring. I see a red wire going from the negative power input terminal to the other end of the board. Does this wire supply ground to both the MCU and motor FET?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The red wire connects the negative power input terminal to FET.
The MCU gnd is at the same  same potential.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I have made the changes as suggested by you. Please refer the updated circuit diagram. I have added a Capacitor(10uF/63v) from pin 30 to pin 31, and pin31 is connected to GND. 

The system works fine on 12V but when supply is 24V the output of PB3 is always LOW (checked with oscilloscope without the FET circuit).

Comment: Ok ! Now I have added another 35V, 230uF Capacitor in parallel to other one. Now 24V works fine too. Can someone explain this concept to me ?
And what do I do so the MOSFET doesn't heat up. I have added heat sink and applied paste.

Comment: What are the technical specifications of the 12V and 24V motor?

Comment: @KanishakKatahra, apparantely you are running both the motor and the MCU using the same power supply and you common ground connections. With using the capacitors between pin 31 and 32 you decoupled the MCU power supply from the rest of the circuit, hence preventing the MCU to reset in case of spikes on power or ground lines which are caused by the motor.